# In Pintool, How to find the name of an routine's caller?

Tags: dynamic-analysis, instrumentation, pintool, multi-process

I want to trace the mutex variables in my rust program(e.g. which mutex called lock() and unlock() methods). And I think there're static methods.

Comment: Why not instrument every `call` instruction and see if the call target is your function of choice?

Answer (score 1):

In `instruction` instrumentation function, you can check if the instruction is indeed a call instruction. Something like -

```
if (INS_IsCall(ins))
    {
        if (INS_IsDirectCall(ins))
        {
```

Then get the name of the routine:

```
if (RTN_FindNameByAddress(INS_DirectBranchOrCallTargetAddress(ins)) 
== "yourfavouritefun")
do something;
        }
}
```

And you can obviously log the caller.

```
VOID Instruction(INS ins, VOID *v) {
ADDRINT insaddress = INS_Address(ins);
if (RTN_FindNameByAddress(insaddress))
  do something more;
....
```

Comment: So how to find the callers of `instruction` (i.e., how to distinguish different callers of the same `instruction`)?